# How do I Compare two char[] arrays for equivalency?

Tags: c#, arrays, compare

Right now, I have two `char` arrays, `foo1[]` and `foo2[]`. When I convert them to string and output to the console, they BOTH appear as `bar`. I know that I can do something like this:

```
int g;
for (int i=0;i<length.foo1;i++) {      // loop from 0 to length of array
    if (foo1[i]=foo2[i]) {             // if foo1[0] and foo2[0] are the same char
    g++;                               // increment a counter by 1
}
else                                   // otherwise...
{
    i=100;                             // set i to something that will halt the loop
}
if (g = length.foo1) {                 // if the incremented counter = length of array
    return true;                       // arrays are equal, since g only increments
}                                      // in the case of a match, g can ONLY equal the
else {                                 // array length if ALL chars match
    return false;                      // and if not true, false.
```

to compare them letter by letter, but I'm guessing there's an easier way. Interestingly, most of the googling I do for `comparing char[] for eqivalency c#` and similar keywords results in a whole mess of info about comparing STRING arrays, or comparing string or char arrays when PART of the array matches something or another...I've not been able to find anything about easy ways of testing char arrays as being equal. Is stepping through each array the best way? or is there some way to compare if foo1=foo2 or foo1==foo2? Neither of those worked for me.

Basically, I need to test if `char foo1[]` and `char foo2[]` are BOTH `{B,A,R}`

Comment: What sort of equivalency are you talking about? How do you want to handle cultural comparisons? Or are you only interested in *ordinal* equivalence? Note that this clearly isn't your actual C# code, as `<>` isn't valid in C#, and you're trying to increment an uninitialized variable. Oh, and then your `if` statement doesn't have a Boolean conditoin. It's not really clear what that code *is* meant to do...

Comment: I'll clarify the question...when I said "I could do something LIKE this"...I didn't clarify that is was pseudocode-ish. I also have NO idea what you mean by the term "cultural comparisons", so I'm not sure if I even need to worry about it.

Comment: Consider "ss" and "ß" ([Eszett](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F)). If you're performing a culture-sensitive comparison, those may be considered equal or not, depending on the culture you use.

Comment: Ahh...got it on the culture-sensitivity. For the purposes of this exercise, cafe does NOT equal café and tschuss does NOT equal tschuß, so handling cultural language differences won't be an issue...in some cases, knowing that cafe & café resolve to not equal will be the desired results.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
string s = new string(foo1);
string t = new string(foo2);

int c = string.Compare(s, t);
if(c==0){
    //its equal
}
```

Comment: This works excellently. Thanks. I was hoping there was something like this to use DIRECTLY on char arrays, but it looks like not.

Comment: This demonstrates how to compare strings, not `char[]`.

Comment: Lol, you are not serious r u

Comment: I came here to learn how to compare two char arrays without having to allocate two strings :(

Answer (score 22):

You are possibly looking for:

```
foo2.SequenceEqual(foo1)
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use the [SequenceEquals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx) to compare the arrays, even though checking both lengths at first has better performance.

Answer (score 1):

```
foo1.ToList().Intersect(foo2.ToList())
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make a function of yours which will be faster then first converting char[] to string then compare two strings.
1.   First compare length of the arrays if they are not equal return false.
2.   start looping through and compare each char, If you find any diff return false else after the loop return true.

```
if(foo1.Length != foo2.Length){ return false;}
for(int i=0;i<foo1.Length;i++){
   if(foo1[i] != foo2[i]){ return false;}
}
return true;
```